# build error when separating c++ code

Tags: c++, mingw, build-error, code-separation

I have recently made a little example in order to practice separating C++ code in `.h` and `.cpp` files using [Geany](http://www.geany.org/). The code compiles without issue, but the following error occurs when I build:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o "parent1" "parent1.cpp" (in directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Geany)
C:\Users\Sabine\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnonGdW.o:parent1.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `grandparent::grandparent(int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o): In function `main':
i:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0.2-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.2-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/main.c:91: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Compilation failed.
```

The source files:

**parent1.h:**

```
#ifndef PARENT1_H
#define PARENT1_H

#include "grandparent.h"

class parent1 :public grandparent
{   private:
       int i ;
    public:
       parent1(int p1a, int p1b, int p1c);
};

#endif
```

**parent1.cpp:**

```
 #include "parent1.h"
    #include "grandparent.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    parent1::parent1(int a, int b, int c)
    : grandparent(a)
    {}
```

Hi thanks for the quick replies.

Remove this line #include "grandparent.h" in parent1.cpp --- that didn`t work. ( Error: expected class-name before {-token  )

**grandparent.h** looks like this:

```
#ifndef GRANDPARENT_H
#define GRANDPARENT_H
class grandparent
{   private:
        int gx; 
    public: 
        grandparent(int gx);    
};
#endif
```

Comment: Remove this line #include "grandparent.h" in parent1.cpp

Comment: Show the contents of grandparent.h

Comment: Also, writing `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice for the reasons outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice.

Comment: @Khnle - how would removing the inclusion in cpp help?  Preprocessor guards prevent it from being a problem.

Comment: @ssell Compilation would have failed if this were the case - OP said that compilation is successful but 'build' (presumably link) is failing.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick replies.      
 
Remove this line #include "grandparent.h" in parent1.cpp --- that didn`t work. ( Error: expected class-name before {-token  )

**grandparent.h** looks like this:

    #ifndef GRANDPARENT_H
    #define GRANDPARENT_H
    
    class grandparent
    { private:
      int gx; 
     public: 
      grandparent(int gx); 
    };
    
    #endif

Answer (score 3):

You need to link with the grandparent object - grandparent.o or the library it belongs to.

UPDATE: In particular you need (assuming you've already compiled grandparent.cpp):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o "parent1" "parent1.cpp" "grandparent.o"
```

I believe that

```
   g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o "parent1" "parent1.cpp" "grandparent.cpp"
```

will also work.

Comment: the error shown is a compile time error. OP didn't even reach the linking phase yet

Comment: Not true.  'ld returned 1 exit status'.  ld is the linker.  g++ will automatically compile and link when the output is not specified as a *.o.

Comment: my bad :) , I was focusing on `grandparent::grandparent(int)`

Comment: How do I link it to grandparent.o ?

Comment: @user3443063 - See edits to answer above.